# Unable to navigate on click of a Link. Getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image: This is my file structure]I am trying to navigate to different url which will open a new component. But every time I am getting an error

I am stuck with this for long, any help will be appreciated.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I have 3 components
Index.js where I have this code

```
return (
      <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/editable-table" component={EditableTable} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

JobseekerMain.js where onClick function is written

```
   <Link
              style={{ color: "#e73a9e" }}
              href="#"
              onClick={this.handleNavigationClick}
              aria-current="page"
            >
              Editable Example
            </Link>
```

```
//function to navigate to editable table
  handleNavigationClick = e => {
    // debugger;
    this.props.history.push({ pathname: "editable-table" });
    console.log("here");
  };
```

and my Component which should appear
EditableTable.js

Comment: If you are using react-router 4+, Did you import { withRouter } from "react-router" and wrap it around your component?

Comment: I am importing this import { withRouter, browserHistory } from "react-router-dom";
in JobSeekerMain.js

Comment: In which file should I import this

Comment: Did you wrap it then? I mean if your component name is JobSeekerMain, you should have something like withRouter(JobSeekerMain). Which version of react router you are using?

Comment: ```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3"
  },
``

Comment: react-router official docs have an awesome example where you can see how to set up your Router and how to access the history prop correctly using withRouter as @G_S mentioned https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: I am importing from react-router-dom not from react-router

Comment: @Amnahkhatun take the time to at least read the link and documentation, react-router is the global package, the link I send you is for web, which use react-router-dom... at least open the link and check the package used...

Comment: Sure Alex I am going through it.  I tried doing this 'withRouter(JobSeekerMain).' and I am getting this error now ```Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(JobSeekerMain) /> outside a <Router>
```

Comment: As the message said, you can't access it cause your JobSeekerMain component is not inside your router. You are only passing the EditableTable to a route. Your JobSeekerMain should have it's own route or be part of some of the routes already set (like for example, beign part of the EditableTable component)

Comment: This is my EditableTable component
https://jsfiddle.net/amnahkhatun/sez036vb/

Comment: I have attached screeshot of my file structure

Comment: @AlexSanchez can you explain this line "your JobSeekerMain component is not inside your router. You are only passing the EditableTable to a route"

Comment: @Amnahkhatun, I added a comment to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196506/discussion-between-amnah-khatun-and-cbdev420 See if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

**index.js**

It seems you're doing everything correct in here. But I don't know if `JobseekerMain.js` is inside the `<BrowserRouter>`. It should be.

Also, you don't need to use the `onClick` property of the `<Link>` component. Are you doing that for any particular reason?

Here's a working example. See if that's what you are looking for.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-grass-bufkj

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AllRoutes/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function AllRoutes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={JobSeekerMain}/>
      <Route exact path='/editable' component={EditableTable}/>
    </Switch>

  );
}

class JobSeekerMain extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>I am JobSeekerMain</div>
        <Link to='/editable'>Editable Table</Link>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}

function EditableTable() {
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Editable Table</div>
      <Link to='/'>JobSeekerMain</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**UPDATE:**

This is how you could use the Link from Material-UI with the Link from react-router-dom.

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-field-fqor1

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import LinkMUI from "@material-ui/core/Link";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AllRoutes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function AllRoutes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={JobSeekerMain} />
      <Route exact path="/editable" component={EditableTable} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

class JobSeekerMain extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>I am JobSeekerMain</div>
        <div>This is option #1: wrap LinkMUI with react-router-dom Link </div>
        <Link to="/editable">
          <LinkMUI>Hi</LinkMUI>
        </Link>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

function EditableTable(props) {
  function handleClick() {
    props.history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am Editable Table</div>
      <div>This is option #2: use LinkMUI and the onClick attribute</div>
      <LinkMUI onClick={handleClick}>JobSeekerMain</LinkMUI>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thankyou for replying I tried the same thing but now nothing is happening. onClick I was using to got to function ```
handleNavigationClick = e => {
    // debugger;
    this.props.history.push({ pathname: "editable-table" });
    console.log("here");
  };
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could check this https://jsfiddle.net/amnahkhatun/sez036vb/3/

Comment: That's a lot of code to go through. Please make an example with minimal functionality to test only the problem you're running into. So far, I can tell you that you're not using the `Link` component correctly. You need to use something like `<Link to='/somepath'>`. You don't need to use `href`

Comment: ```
 <Link
             to="/editable"
              style={{ color: "#e73a9e" }}
              // href="#"
              // onClick={this.handleNavigationClick}
             
              aria-current="page"
            >
              Editable Example
            </Link>
```

Comment: Do I have to import Link from react-router-dom? currently it is like this.import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

Comment: The `Link` you're importing from Material-UI is just an UI (user interface) component so it looks good on your screen. You have to options. You can import `Link` from `react-router-dom` and wrap your Material-UI `Link` with it (you'll need to import one of them with a different name. They cannot both be named Link). Or you can keep using only the `Link` from Material-UI and use the `onClick` property to do `history.push('/somepath');` and not use the `Link` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: yes I was using onClick for the same purpose where i was getting push of undefined

Comment: Like this
```
   <Link
              style={{ color: "#e73a9e" }}
              href="#"
              onClick={this.handleNavigationClick}
              aria-current="page"
            >
              Editable Example
            </Link>
```
 handleNavigationClick = e => {
    // debugger;
    this.props.history.push({ pathname: "editable-table" });
    console.log("here");
  };

Comment: I will add a CodeSandbox to my answer so you can see both options!

Comment: You're welcome. See if that helps. I encourage you to read the docs for the `react-router`. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196506/discussion-between-amnah-khatun-and-cbdev420).